# Automate creation of large symbolic matrix

Tags: maxima

Can this matrix be generated in a less manual way? It's okay for 4 x 4, but I need something larger. Thanks

```
 -->    L : matrix([L11,L12,L13,L14],[L21,L22,L23,L24],[L31,L32,L33,L34],[L41,L42,L43,L44]);
(L) matrix(
        [L11,   L12,    L13,    L14],
        [L21,   L22,    L23,    L24],
        [L31,   L32,    L33,    L34],
        [L41,   L42,    L43,    L44]
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the question and note the noun form for L in the concat function ('L)

```
L:genmatrix(lambda([i,j], concat('L,i,j)), 3, 3);
    (L) matrix(
            [L11,   L12,    L13],
            [L21,   L22,    L23],
            [L31,   L32,    L33]
        )
```

For a diagonal matrix

```
R:genmatrix(lambda([i,j], if i=j then concat('R,i) else 0), 3, 3);

    (R) matrix(
            [R1, 0, 0],
            [0, R2, 0],
            [0, 0, R3]
        )
```

Comment: If you only need Ljk elements instead of some specific values, maybe you could just skip the construct entirely. You can write L[1, 3], L[2, k], L[j, k], etc and use those like an ordinary variable.

Comment: @Robert Dodier Thanks for the suggestion, that would be the sensible thing to do if I was staying within Maxima, but for this case I'm using Maxima to generate a symbolic form of the solution to evaluate numerically within some other software. Thanks for all your Maxima works! it's a great help to the algebraically challenged.

Comment: Glad to hear it's useful for you. I'm interested to hear about the problem you're working on, if you want to briefly describe it.

Comment: @Robert Dodier Thanks for the interest, it's nothing exciting, just the steady-state ac response of an electric circuit where R and L are the resistance and inductance matrices with L calculated using finite elements. Regards,

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you bumped into a need for matrices of unspecified size? Sometimes FE methods are described that way, with matrices that have ellipses in the middle. Maxima can only handle matrices of specific size at present, but from time to time I think about handling unspecific size as well.

Comment: @Robert Dodier For the work I'm doing the matrix dimensions (square) are only the size of the prescribed number of coils within the system rather than related to the number of degrees of freedom of the assembled FE matrices, so a very large matrix of unspecified length wouldn't be required, but you can be sure that it would be useful in some fields.